# Schematron XML validation in C# using XSL file

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xslt, schematron

I need to perform Schematron validation on `XML` files. I've googled a lot and the closest thing I've come to an solution is using [Schematron package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Schematron/) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa468554(v=msdn.10)):

```
    public static bool SchemaTronValidation(string xml, string xsl)
    {
        //Create schema and validator
        var xslStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xsl ?? ""));

        Schema schematronSchema = new Schema();
        schematronSchema.Load(xslStream);

        Validator validator = new Validator();
        validator.AddSchema(schematronSchema);

        //Validate
        var xmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml ?? ""));
        var res = validator.Validate(xmlStream); //fails here

        return true;
    }
```

When testing this code with valid `XML` and `XSL` files, It crashes when I call Validate(`xmlStream`) on validator. It says Operation is not allowed and I am not sure why. Do anyone know more on how to validate Schematron files in `C#`? I'm baffled that there doesn't seem to be much support on this kind of validation.

The example in Microsoft docs are using XSD and not XSL files for the schema, could this be why it does not work?

Comment: First start with either an online validation tool or from Visual Studio menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml string into view.  Errors will show up like compiler error in the Error List.

Comment: I don't know much about C#, but if you're using System.Xml.Schema, it only works with W3C XML Schema (XSD). If you're using NMatrix.Schematron, I would assume it can work with Schematron schemas, which would usually be a .sch file. (If you follow the XSLT-based reference implementation for Schematron validation, then you would transform the .sch file to an XSL file and then use that XSL file to process the document you want to validate. But I would guess that NMatrix.Schematron would allow you to simply provide the .sch file as your schema.)